# Query "Today" on google forms timestamp column?

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp, google-sheets-formula

I am using query and importrange to create sub-reports from a large report created by a google form.  I'd like to only pull records from "Today" in the sub-reports.

Right now, I have:

=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1puPOyfFIYV04afQVLK76weqYbIHrWBhFjHS-AB0OnGE/edit#gid=1883486031","Form Responses 1!A:AV"), "select Col1, Col8, Col43, Col44, Col45, Col46, Col47, Col48 where Col3 = '2008 Red' and Col1 = date '" & text(today(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'")

Col1 is the Timestamp column generated automatically by google forms.  I know that the formats don't match and that this is the problem.  I can't change the format in the source (google form generated sheet).  Is there a way to do this conversion IN my query formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change = to contains. And is seems like you shared the sheet publicly. so i can see the names that have entered the from. I changes the link in your post and mine...

```
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1puPOyfFILK76weqYbIHrWBhFjHS-AB0OnGE/edit#gid=1883486031","Form Responses 1!A:AV"), "select Col1, Col8, Col43, Col44, Col45, Col46, Col47, Col48 where Col3 = '2008 Red' and Col1 contains date '"&text(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Comment: Thank you!  On all fronts :). Worked like a charm!